# How do you add the content of two textfields?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

In my app I have got two textfields, one label and one button. I managed to get the content of the one textfield to be displayed in the label, but I want to display the content of both of the textfields.

```
@IBAction func buttonPushed(sender: UIButton) {  
        Label.text = "\(textfield1.text)"  
        + "\(textfield2.text)"
```

The code above is the closest I´ve come, but the Label displays:

> Optional"whatever I typed in the textfield"Optional"whatever I typed
>   in the textfield"

Comment: You are concatenating strings not adding numbers. Cast the text field values to numbers first

Comment: You should clarify if you're trying to add numbers or concatenate strings. My guess is the latter. The problem is because a text field doesn't need to have text - the value is optional. You need to unwrap the values before putting them in the text of that label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unwrap the text

```
Label.text = textfield1.text! + textfield2.text!
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating strings, not adding numbers. In order to add the values, you need to cast the textfield value to a number like:

```
field.text!.toInt()
```

the `!` unwraps the value to remove the "Optional". and `toInt()` casts a string (text) to and integer.

In the end, you code will look something like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonPushed(sender: UIButton) {  
        Label.text = "\(textfield1.text!.toInt())"  
        + "\(textfield2.text!.toInt())"
```